# Display files which contains a word on more then three lines?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to display all files which contain a specific word on more then three lines.

i.e. file:

```
Andrew is so nice, 
and Andrew want some ice,
but Andrew doesn't roll the dice.
```

So this file contains Andrew on more than three lines, so it will be displayed.

I used grep -or '\' but it list all files which contain "word" on at least 1 line.

Comment: consecutive lines or just at least three occurrences in the file?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
  grep -c Andrew * | awk -F: '{if ($2 >=3) print $1}'
```

It works because grep -c prints "file:count" for each file, and `-F:` tells awk that the colon separates fields.

Answer (score 2):

The following shell script may be useful:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` DIRECTORY STRING"
  exit 1
fi

for file in $1/* ; do
    if [ `cat $file 2>/dev/null | grep -c $2` -ge 3 ]; then 
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

The script should be run with two arguments:

- `DIRECTORY` - the directory where you want to search for files which contains a word on more then three lines
- `STRING` - the word for seeking.

---

Or, in a single command for files from the current directory and the word "Andrew":

```
for file in *;do if [ `cat $file 2>/dev/null|grep -c Andrew` -ge 3 ];then echo $file;fi;done
```

Comment: Or more concisely: `for f in ./*; do [[ $(grep -c Andrew "$f") -ge 3 ]] && echo "$f"; done`